# Editing data in Android internal storage using a service

Tags: android, sqlite, service, synchronization

I coded an android app that has its background service to do data syncing when app is not running. How do I modify files in internal mem  or records in an sqlite dbase of an android app using the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the same as if your in a normal application , since you are passed in a `Context`. One important point I want to point out is, if your Application starts up and your `Service` also starts up and both needs to use the database, then you will need to make sure there will be no conflict. You can simply store your instance in your sub-`Application` class to make sure only one instance of the database was created.